# $(\frac{d}{dt} + 2a)\int w^2 dx \le 0 \implies w=0$ where $a>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

$F(t) := \int w^2 dx$ where x is a vector and $a,t>0$

Given that $(\frac{d}{dt} - 2a)F(t) \le 0$

How do I deduce that $w=0$?

My idea was to do:

$(\frac{d}{dt} + 2a)F(t) \le 0$

$\implies $$\frac{d}{dt}F(t) \le 2aF(t)$

$\implies $$\int \frac{d}{dt}F(t) \le \int 2aF(t)$

$\implies $$F(t) \le \int 2aF(t)$

Since $a, F(t) > 0 $ $\implies $$\int 2aF(t)\ge0$

$ \implies F(t) \le 0$ **just realised this line is not true either**

Since $F(t) \ge 0 \implies F(t)=0 \implies w=0$

The only line am i not sure about is:

$\int \frac{d}{dt}F(t) \le \int 2aF(t)$ $\implies $$F(t) \le \int 2aF(t)$

because there should be a constant of integration introduced somewhere

The soln i was given was that $F(t)$ is bdd above by $G(t)$ where $(\frac{d}{dt}-2a)G(t) = 0$ and $G(0)=0$ so $\implies G=0$
but since $F(t) \le 0 \implies F=0 \implies w=0$

I cant seem to understand this since answer since G isnt defined explicitly

Comment: $G(t)$ is defined expticitly: $G(t) = 0$ for all $t$. What you need to do is to make use of the fact that $G$ is the solution of the differential equation $G' = 2aG$ with $G(0) = 0$ to show that it must also be an upper bound for $F$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair but how does G being a soln to that diff eq make it an upper bound for f